# is there any way that we don't need to initialize char VarName with 0?

Tags: java, arrays, char, calculator

I was trying to create a calculator using array and switch case(for +,-,*,/). But i guess my char[] is always at 0th index... please help me.(is there any way that we don't need to initialize char operator with 0? this is just my getData class, if you want to see the whole calculator code I will post it too.
thank-you.♥

```
/* DESIRED I/O
enter array length: 3
2
+

5
-

5
=
(answer)*/


//wholeCode; //struggling in this...please help me
package calculator1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class getdata0  {
int number;
char operator;
double answer;
double num[]= new double[number];
char op[]=new char[number];
int i;  
    void getData0()
    {
    
        try (Scanner object = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        
                System.out.print("Enter number: ");
                number=object.nextInt();
                
            double num[]= new double[number];
            char op[]=new char[number];
                for(i=0;i<num.length;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("getting data"+(i+1));
                    num[i]=object.nextInt();
                    op[i]=object.next().charAt(0);
                    
                }
                }
        }
}
package calculator1;

public class addition extends getdata0 
{
    /*int number;    IGNORE!!
    double num[]= new double[number];
    double answer;*/
    
    double add()
    {System.out.println("adding...");
        /*for(int add=0;add<num.length;add++)
        {
            answer=answer+num[add];
            }
*///NOT SURE WHICH ONE TO USE.
    
        /*for(double no:num)
        {
        answer+=no;
        }*/
    return answer;
    }
}
package calculator1;

public class substraction extends addition{
double sub()
public class division extends substraction{
double div() 
public class multiplication extends division{
double mul()
    
public class chooseoperators extends multiplication 
{

    void chooseOperator()
    {int y=0;
    
        System.out.println("Operating...");
        
        for(y=0;y<op.length;y++)
        
        System.out.println("Operating inside switch");
        
        switch(op[y])
        { 
        case '+': add();
        break;
        case '-':sub();
        break;
        case '/':div();
        break;
        case '*':mul();
        break;
        case '=':System.out.println(answer);
        break;
        }System.out.println("operation end");
}}


package calculator1;

public class Run extends chooseoperators
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        chooseoperators objectC=new chooseoperators();
        
        objectC.getData0();
    
        System.out.println(objectC.num.length);
        objectC.chooseOperator();
        System.out.println(objectC.op.length);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs of your code? It's unclear what your code is trying to do.

Comment: @Sweeper edited.

Comment: That's way too much code... If I understand correctly, for the given input (`2+5-5=` each character on a separate line), you want the output to be `num arr:3` and `op arr:3`? if so please edit.

Comment: i want to store each number in numarr and each operator in oparr.... and yes i just want   2+5-5=(as input) Answer (as output)

Comment: Okay, so I understand correctly. Please edit your question to provide the minimal necessary code to reproduce the issue. and explain clearly what you expect the code to do, and what the code actually does. This is called a [mcve].

Comment: can you check my getdata0 class and chooseoperator class maybe youll understand what i am trying to say...thankyou

Comment: @Sweeper edited